# typescript recordtype add items dynamically

Tags: typescript, record

I need to store the following data in any structure.

"Total Count": 
"Error Count": 
"Success Count":

The keys are known upfront, however the values will only be determined at different stages in the processing cycle.  What is the best data structure which I can use to store this data.  I can convert the keys to an enum and use the record type but not sure how to proceed from there.

Comment: Please post code. this is incredibly broad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your need:

```js
type DataCount = Record<'total' | 'success' | 'error', number>;

const sample: DataCount = {
  total: 0,
  success: 0,
  error: 0
}

// increment count
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I have one more requirement where I know the values only later on.  How do I do this?